# Паралельные тесты в testNG.xml

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, testng

Помогите составить testng.xml для паралельного запуска тестов.
Есть тесты

```
@BeforeClass
@Parameters("path")
public void openPage(String path, ITestContext testContext){...}

@Test(description = "This TC#01", priority = 1)
public void testBigCSVPositive(ITestContext testContext){...}

@Test(dependsOnMethods = "testBigCSVPositive", priority = 1)
public void testBigCSVNegative(ITestContext testContext){...}

@Test(description = "This TC#02", priority = 2)
public void testBigCSVNegative(ITestContext testContext){...}

@Test(dependsOnMethods = "testBigCSVNegative", priority = 2)
public void reportNegativeTest(ITestContext testContext){...}
```

И сам xml

```
<suite name="SuiteBigCSV" parallel="methods" thread-count="5" verbose="5">

<test name="506">
    <parameter name="path"
               value="src/test/resources/locators/506.properties"/>
    <classes>
        <class name="tests.CSVBig">
        <methods>
            <include name="testBigCSVPositive"/>
            <include name="reportPositiveTest"/>
            <include name="testBigCSVNegative"/>
            <include name="reportNegativeTest"/>
        </methods>
    </class>
    </classes>
</test>

<test name="507">
    <parameter name="path"
               value="src/test/resources/locators/507.properties"/>
    <classes>
        <class name="tests.CSVBig">
        <methods>
            <include name="testBigCSVPositive"/>
            <include name="reportPositiveTest"/>
            <include name="testBigCSVNegative"/>
            <include name="reportNegativeTest"/>
        </methods>
    </class>
    </classes>
</test>

<test name="505">
    <parameter name="path"
               value="src/test/resources/locators/505.properties"/>
    <classes>
        <class name="tests.CSVBig">
        <methods>
            <include name="testBigCSVPositive"/>
            <include name="reportPositiveTest"/>
            <include name="testBigCSVNegative"/>
            <include name="reportNegativeTest"/>
        </methods>
    </class>
    </classes>
</test>

<test name="504">
    <parameter name="path"
               value="src/test/resources/locators/504.properties"/>
    <c<classes>
        <class name="tests.CSVBig">
        <methods>
            <include name="testBigCSVPositive"/>
            <include name="reportPositiveTest"/>
            <include name="testBigCSVNegative"/>
            <include name="reportNegativeTest"/>
        </methods>
    </class>
    </classes>
</test>

<test name="501">
    <parameter name="path"
               value="src/test/resources/locators/501.properties"/>
    <classes>
        <class name="tests.CSVBig">
        <methods>
            <include name="testBigCSVPositive"/>
            <include name="reportPositiveTest"/>
            <include name="testBigCSVNegative"/>
            <include name="reportNegativeTest"/>
        </methods>
    </class>
    </classes>
</test>
```

Пробовал менять parallel на classes, tests все равно тесты запускаются в 1 потоке. Спасибо

Comment: Может проблема в том, как Вы запускаете тесты? Как Вы это делаете? Из IDE через какой-нибудь плагин, через maven surefire plugin или через gradle, и т.д.?

Comment: через мавен maven surefire plugin

Comment: а Вы указываете путь до testng.xml файла? через suiteXmlFile?

Comment: да, ниже скинул pom

Comment: [документация](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/testng.html#Running_tests_in_parallel) говорит что надо добавить `<parallel>methods</parallel>` и `<threadCount>5</threadCount>` непосредственно в `configuration` плагина.

Comment: Наверное нашел подвох, тест запускается в потоках, но в xml берет только 1 метод и дублирует в потоках и что-то мен подсказывает, что это из-за статических методов инициализации локаторов

Answer (score 0):

Вот кусок моего pom

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-surefire-plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                <argLine>
                    -javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar
                </argLine>
                <systemPropertyVariables>
                    <environment>${environment}</environment>
                </systemPropertyVariables>
                <suiteXmlFiles>
                    <suiteXmlFile>src/test/resources/testNG/${testNGxml}</suiteXmlFile>
                </suiteXmlFiles>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                    <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                    <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```